# Rounding through type ascription

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I would like to introduce a custom class, say `Decimal2`, so that I would be able to round through type ascription:

```
val x: Decimal2 = 1.2345
// 1.24
```

So far I've tried this:

```
class Decimal2(val value: Double)

object Decimal2 {

  def apply(value: Double) =
    BigDecimal(value).
    setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).
    toDouble

  implicit def doubleToDecimal2(x: Double) = Decimal2(x)

}

val a: Decimal2 = 1.2345
```

But:

1. the last line apparently fails.
2. return type of apply method is `Double`, not `Decimal2`

How can I reach my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is by explicitly creating a new instance of `Decimal2` from `apply` method.

```
object Decimal2 {
  def apply(value: Double): Decimal2 =
    new Decimal2(BigDecimal(value)
      .setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
      .toDouble)

  implicit def doubleToDecimal2(x: Double): Decimal2 = Decimal2(x)
}
```

Another option is to tag the type:

```
trait RoundTo2
type Decimal2 = Double with RoundTo2

object Decimal2 {
  def apply(value: Double): Decimal2 = {
    BigDecimal(value)
      .setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
      .toDouble
  }.asInstanceOf[Double with RoundTo2]
}
implicit def doubleToDecimal2(x: Double): Decimal2 = Decimal2(x)

val a: Decimal2 = 1.2345
```

Comment: Will you elaborate a bit on "tag the type"? Does it relate to `ClassTag` and type erasure?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov, I got the term `tagging` from the book [The Type Astronaut’s Guide to Shapeless](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html). Here we are tagging `Doube` using `asInstanceOf` with a phantom type `RoundTo2`, thus getting a compile time behavior of `Double with RoundTo2` and a runtime behavior of `Double`.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to do this with scala 3 opaque type.
I would say even more, opaque type is made for this kind of thing.

```
// a Decimal2 is a Double with some restriction
opaque type Decimal2 = Double
object Decimal2 :
  def apply(d2 : Double) : Decimal2 = BigDecimal(d2).setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble

// extension method to Decimal2 to have a back conversion to a full Double 
extension (d2 : Decimal2)
  def double : Double = d2

// implicit conversion for convenience
given doubleToDecimal2 : Conversion[Double, Decimal2] = Decimal2(_)
```

now you can use it like you want :

```
val d2 : Decimal2 = 1.23456 // 1.23
d2 // Decimal2
d2.double // double
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two requirements.

1. Make Decimal2 class provides a method that returns a rounded `Double` value.
2. Convert Double value to Decimal2 class

Here is a straightforward approach.

```scala
  case class Decimal2(value: Double){
    def toDouble: Double = BigDecimal(value).
      setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
  }

  implicit class DoubleImprovement(val x: Double){
    def toDecimal2: Decimal2 = Decimal2(x)
  }
  
  println(1.2345.toDecimal2.toDouble)
```

Comment: Thanks, but `val a: Decimal2 = 1.2345` still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.